# Why does google maps js api marker mousein event happen when slightly out of marker?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

My goal is to have the following behavior:
mousein on marker - open infowindow;
mouseout of marker - close infowindow;

But, when I mousein from top of the marker, still not reaching the marker, but very close to the marker from top, the infowindow is opened; then, the mouse is on the tip of the infowindow, which now triggers the mouseout event from the marker - probably since the mouse is now considered on the tip of the infowindow. Then, the infowindow closes, and the mousein is triggered, and this happens infinitely.

Is there a way to "tell" the API to only trigger marker mousein event when the mouse is actually on the marker? Or, is there another way to avoid this loop?

EDIT: here is how fast the loop goes:

```
web.js:1447 mouseover: 10:53:56.209
web.js:1452 mouseout: 10:53:56.233
web.js:1447 mouseover: 10:53:56.258
web.js:1452 mouseout: 10:53:56.291
web.js:1447 mouseover: 10:53:56.297
web.js:1452 mouseout: 10:53:56.315
web.js:1447 mouseover: 10:53:56.339
web.js:1452 mouseout: 10:53:56.376
web.js:1447 mouseover: 10:53:56.401
web.js:1452 mouseout: 10:53:56.435
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no event such as `mousein` in the JavaScript UI Events in Google Maps JS v3. You have to use `mouseover` instead of `mousein`. Please check the [Events documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events) to learn more about events and also the [Marker class](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/#Marker) reference. You may see this in the doc:

> Events: `animation_changed`, `click`, `clickable_changed`, `cursor_changed`, `dblclick`, `drag`, `dragend`, `draggable_changed`, `dragstart`, `flat_changed`, `icon_changed`, `mousedown`, `mouseout`, `mouseover`, `mouseup`, `position_changed`, `rightclick`, `shape_changed`, `title_changed`, `visible_changed`, `zindex_changed`

It should be used like this:

```
marker.addListener('mouseover', function() {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });

marker.addListener('mouseout', function() {
  infowindow.close();
});
```

Click on this [link](http://jsbin.com/kinamuf/edit?html,css,js,output) to see it in action.

Comment: Yes, those are the events I used, mouseover and mouseout.

Comment: I added some output to show how fast the loop goes (again, not touching the mouse.)

Comment: It would be best if we can see this one in action. I suggest you make a self contained sample using a JSBin or JSFiddle that would replicate this issue.